# CakePHP: how to create a duplicate row in aferSave Callback function

Tags: cakephp, callback

In Cakephp's afterSave callback function I am trying to create a new record but it's saving empty data.

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    if ($any_condition) {
        $record = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $this->data[$this->alias]['id'])));
        $record[$this->alias]['id'] = null;
        $this->create();
        $this->save($record);

    } 

}
```

When I see the record in db, everything is empty. I need to know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what's the result in `$this->data[$this->alias]`?

Comment: @NewbeeDev, it's the data of the current record.

Comment: whats the result in your `$record`?

Comment: @NewbeeDev It's a full row data.

Comment: I don't see how it's saving an empty data if `$record` has a valid data

Comment: try this https://gyazo.com/c3a3a7f9bb99bf38ae66403994e43ea9

Comment: ```if ($any_condition) {``` Looks like it would never be true.

Comment: @Kelvin, that was only for demo purpose. Let's suppose that's always true.

Answer (score 0):

ok, based on your code it looks like you would be calling afterSave an infinite amount of times. If you need to save duplicate information, I wouldn't do it in the callback. I would do it from the controller or create a model function.

In the same model create your own function. Then instead of save you can call saveDuplicate. This is assuming cake 2.

```
function saveDuplicate($data)
{
     $data = [$data, $data];
     $this->saveAll($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the ClassRegistry class to get a new fresh instance of a model

```
public function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    if ($any_condition) {
        $record = $this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' =>         $this->data[$this->alias]['id'])));
        $model = ClassRegistry::init($this->alias);
        $model->create($record);
        $model->save($record);

    } 

}
```